# Declaring an array of structs within the same struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I'm not positive this is even possible, but I am basically trying to define a struct with an array of the same struct inside of it, like so

```
struct Node {
    int numMatches = 0;
    Node* leaves[26] = {};
};
```

Each node would contain a fixed-length array of pointers to other nodes (representing letters). I'm trying to recurse through these nodes, going into the relevant leaf whenever I need. I would initialize a "head" Node* array and bubble down that way. It's seg faulting immediately, and I can see why that might be - it doesn't know how much memory to alloc to an array of such structs. Not quite sure how to solve the problem though.

Pretty simple issue, but I haven't found any C++/C specific threads with this same question.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not hit compile and see if it works?

Comment: of course it does. The array contains pointers to structs, not structs. You have to allocate each one as you want to use it.

Comment: `Node* leaves[26] = {NULL};` would initialize the array of pointer to NULL. Better than nothing I guess. We would need to see your context code to help you further.

Comment: How are you initialize these `Node*` pointers? Can you provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your problem please?

Comment: @NathanOliver If the code segfaults, they appearantly already compilled the code.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE] that segfaults. Without seeing your code it is pretty hard to guess why your program segfaults. And also why is this tagged c++ ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question has two aspects, at least one of which the community doesn't like.  First aspect: can you have a pointer to a structure inside the structure?  Yes.  This is a standard thing to do in C++.  It's not what's causing your problem.  You're getting a seg fault, which is almost certainly due to you referencing memory badly.  People are downvoting and advocating putting your question on hold, because you haven't given sufficient information for us to tell you exactly what's causing the seg fault.  Edit your question with more code, and you'll get good answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `struct` you didn't use an array of the `same struct`, but an array of the `pointers to the same struct` - and it makes the difference.

**`Pointers`** have **known length** (e. g. 32-bit in 32-bit operating systems) *regardless of the object they point to*, so your struct simply allocates (probably)

- 32 bits = 4 bytes for `mumMatches`
- 26 * 32 bits = 26 * 4 bytes = 104 bytes for `leaves`

  ---
- 108 bytes altogether